# Where is the "ng serve" for nodejs? Are there a similar tools for other languages?

Tags: node.js, angular

`ng serve` is absolutely amazing for my workflow.  When writing or editing my angular code, all I need to do is hit save, look at the already running instance of my project, and I can see if I like the changes or not, then repeat.

My question is, where can I get a tool that works like that for... well everything? When I swap from the front end of my MEAN app to the back end the difference is jarring.

I have to write or edit some piece of code, hit save, run `node app.js` in console, check the changes, hit `ctrl+c` to stop the service, change more code and repeat. It's obnoxious in comparison.

Is it a small issue? I mean, yeah. Am I being entitled? Also yeah, probably. It's just such a glaring difference when swapping between the two. I just want to be able to use a similar command when I develop in other environments and languages.

Are there options out there for other languages I just don't know about? Is there a simple script senior devs use that I'm not privy to? Do I just need to suck it up and appreciate the convenience where I have it?

Thanks in advance for any advice you all may have!

Comment: [forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) and [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) might help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure if this is what you are looking for. But I know for node there is a package called

### [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon)

nodemon helps automatically restart the node application whenever a file is changed and saved.

---

```
// Installation
npm install -g nodemon
```

Comment: This is wonderful! Thank you! Now I just need this for literally every language ever and I can be a happy little developer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `supervisor` to watch for file changes and it will automatically serve the latest code

install it like this:

```
npm install supervisor -g
```

Use the it like following

```
supervisor app.js
```

More on supervisor [here](https://github.com/petruisfan/node-supervisor/)